# C# extension methods to fixed byte array?

Tags: c#, pointers, struct, extension-methods

Is there any way to implement an extension method for an 'unsafe fixed byte array'?

I have some structs which have few fixed byte array fields.

I have to use the "pointer style" to do the things in this project.

Any help will be appreaciated!

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Extension methods extend class instances, nothing else.

Comment: This is sad then :( I will have to make the cast hard-coded every time I reference that fields :/

Comment: Or you could just refactor your code to use classes instead of structs.

Comment: I can't. The project have to be as light as possible to the CPU. I have to use structs to cast to/from them with pointers, because this is the fastest way to make this job.

Comment: You could create a container class for your structs and extend that. As long as you don't instantiate a whole bunch of them you should be fine.